# Create basic form using spring 3 mvc framework

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

I am new to Spring Framework . I am trying to create and submit a basic form, but I am not receiving a 404 error response from the second page.

MainController.java:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/dangki", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView student() {
    return new ModelAndView("dangki", "command", new Student());
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/addStudent", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addStudent(@ModelAttribute("SpringFramework") Student myStudent,
        ModelMap model) {
    model.addAttribute("sinhvien", myStudent);
    return "ketqua";

}
```

dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd
">

    <context:component-scan base-package="controller"/>
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <bean id="viewResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
          p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
          p:suffix=".jsp" />

</beans>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>redirect.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

dangki.jsp

```
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Đăng kí</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Đăng kí</h1>
        <form:form action="/SpringFramework/addStudent.html" method="POST">
            Tên:  <form:input type="text" path="name" value="sss"/> <br>
 ID: <form:input type="number" path="id" value="sss"/> <br>
 <input type="submit" value="Đăng kí">
 </form:form>
 </body>

</html>
```

ketqua.jsp

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        ${sinhvien.name}
        ${sinhvien.id}
    </body>
</html>
```

**What am I missing?**

Comment: refer to this - http://www.mkyong.com/spring3/spring-3-mvc-hello-world-example/

Comment: I have done it . Anyway , thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please rewrite this line into controller.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/SpringFramework/addStudent", method = RequestMethod.POST)
```

Comment: tks very much , I did it .

Answer (score 0):

i have this is working. please write this line into controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/country", method = RequestMethod.GET)

public ModelAndView country() {
     ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("countrymaster");
     model.addObject("school", school);
}
```

Comment: I have done it by an other way . Anyway , tks so much

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that your controller definition is just like this:

```
@Controller
public class StudentController {

//... your code here
}
```

You have to change the form to post the data to the request mapping you declared, so:

```
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Đăng kí</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Đăng kí</h1>
        <form:form action="/addStudent/SpringFramework" method="POST">
            Tên:  <form:input type="text" path="name" value="sss"/> <br>
 ID: <form:input type="number" path="id" value="sss"/> <br>
 <input type="submit" value="Đăng kí">
 </form:form>
 </body>
</html>
```

By the way `SpringFramework` is a really poor choise for a variable name, I would use `student` for example.

Comment: I have done it by an other way . Anyway , tks so much